# how to configure wildfly to run as service on window server which bind to 0.0.0.0

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly, application-server

I am running wildfly application server on windows server and if i run wildfly using standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0 then i am able to access over server IP but if i run wildfly after installing service.bat start then it works only with localhost:port.

How i can configure wildfly to run as service on windows server with bind to 0.0.0.0 ?

I am using wildfly 15.0.0  and i have tried to install service using below command :

```
service.bat install /controller 0.0.0.0:9990
```

using above as mentioned i can access management console over server IP.

Answer (score 0):

This is in the context of management port only and you are still able to get application bind to IP.

For the management console.. can you try a change in standalone-full.xml

for :

```
 <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
```

to

```
 <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="0.0.0.0"/>
        </interface>
```